# In Google Sheets how do you show a grouped bar chart for only one variable?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, graph, charts, layer

In google sheets, I want to display grouped bars for one variable only, whilst displaying the rest of the bars as regular "fat" bars. With the way I have it set up currently, the other single valued columns scale smaller, as you can see here:

[image: Current Visualisation]

My desired effect is akin to this:
[image]

Comment: should be doable... share a copy / sample of your sheet

Comment: @player0 [Here you go](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kY85b5u3z6-yL37HiSdreaHag1iapDx6HBl3B6bZz60/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: @player0 Ah, sorry about that. My bad. Should be available now mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can be done like this:

[image]

with stacked charts:

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sIK1RLugY2RCnhg2eGjeSZ4J3HxgAmwa0RY0awR3yBU/edit#gid=0)